# Please help me find out what these letters mean

Tags: word-requests

What do these letters mean, and are they from a store or market?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Where are the letters?

Comment: If you zoom in you can faintly see characters, but c'mon.  In any case, there are threads like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/t7cgbk/%E5%BF%AB%E9%97%AE%E5%BF%AB%E7%AD%94_quick_help_thread_translation_requests/) on Reddit where these kinds of questions can be asked.

Answer (score 0):

"達豪淺水?", this is from a sign of a Chinese store with the letter, or letters, to the right hidden behind the post. If the store is located in Hongkong, one of the missing letters could be "灣". 達豪 is the name of the business, and 淺水灣 (Repulse Bay) is the location it associates with. However, the guess above may not be correct, as the full text is unknown, and the Chinese can read in either direction (left-right or right to left) which will yield different results.